# Create animated gif from similar consecutive frames with ffmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg

When I want to create an animated gif from a photo set, ffmpeg merges similar consecutive frames into one frame. How can I prevent this? My ffmpeg command is as follows:

```
ffmpeg -y -i frame_%03d.png -lavfi "palettegen" outputFilePath

ffmpeg -framerate 1 -y -f image2 -i frame_%03d.png -i paletteFilePath -lavfi "paletteuse" outputFilePath
```

please guide me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a one-pass solution to create an animated GIF:

```
ffmpeg -i "frame_%3d.png" -framerate 12 -filter_complex "fps=12,split=2[palette_in][gif];[palette_in]palettegen[palette_out];[gif]fifo[gif_fifo]; [gif_fifo][palette_out]paletteuse" -y output.gif
```

Extended explanation here:
https://quinbenson.wordpress.com/2019/07/15/ffmpeg-png-to-animated-gif/